# gem development (not load other Gemfile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've an issue with gem file development, for example I'm creating a gem with executable command.

It all works well, I can run command, BUT I've issue that if I'm trying to run command inside another project folder it's USING Gemfile from this second project.

Can I somehow disable it?
I want only to use Gemfile (and .gemspec) from my gem, and not with folder where it was executed.

I have a gem `github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db` (version in master branch is not released yet, so you need to build it locally), gem build ..., then gem install ..., and then go to your project dir and run "railsdb". When you run it, it's trying to load gems from local folder Gemfile.

Thanks
Igor

Comment: Can you add more detail to this question? Names of gems, perhaps your Gemfile ...

Comment: Two questions: first, is your Gem trying to use Bundler directly itself? Second, are you using RVM (or `rubygems-bundler` outside of RVM)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the rubygems-bundler gem, executing commands provided by a gem will load the bundle of your current directory. You can prohibit this from happening for a particular gem providing commands in various ways. One way:

```
export NOEXEC_EXCLUDE=my_gem_command
```

See https://github.com/rvm/rubygems-bundler for more information about rubygems-bundler.